# Mocking an enum using Mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, enums, mockito, final

I need to mock the following enum:

```
public enum PersonStatus
{
    WORKING,
    HOLIDAY,
    SICK      
}
```

This is because it is used in the following class that I am testing:

**Class under test:**

```
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Integer>
{
    List<Person> findByStatus(PersonStatus personStatus);
}
```

Here is my current test attempt:

**Current test:**

```
public class PersonRepositoryTest {

    private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonRepositoryTest.class);

    //Mock the PersonRepository class
    @Mock
    private PersonRepository PersonRepository;

    @Mock
    private PersonStatus personStatus;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        assertThat(PersonRepository, notNullValue());
        assertThat(PersonStatus, notNullValue());
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByStatus() throws ParseException {

        List<Person> personlist = PersonRepository.findByStatus(personStatus);
        assertThat(personlist, notNullValue());
    }
}
```

Which Gives following error:

**error:**

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot mock/spy class PersonStatus
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you *sure* you need to mock `PersonStatus` ? Couldn't you just use the actual instances?

Comment: I don't think you want to mock the enum - you want to pass various values of the enum in your test and check that the result is as expected.

Comment: @assylias please provide answer showing how to do so

Comment: why you want to mock enum?

Comment: you need to simply pass parameter like `PersonStatus.WORKING` or `PersonStatus.SICK`. whichever it is and then check it with your expected result.

Comment: What a coincidence! I've solved the same problem 
five minutes ago, by changing mockito version from 1.8.1 to 1.9.5. I hope it helps you.

Comment: Regarding the question whether you should mock an enum: if your code contains an enumeration where the items themselves do quickly change, it could be you want to mock the enum. So once again the "it depends" phrase comes into play :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `testFindByStatus` is trying to assert that the `findByStatus` does not return null.

If the method works the same way regardless of the value of the `personStatus` param, just pass one of them:

```
@Test
public void testFindByStatus() throws ParseException {
    List<Person> personlist = PersonRepository.findByStatus(WORKING);
    assertThat(personlist, notNullValue());
}
```

If the behaviour may be different for the other possible values, you can test each of them:

```
@Test
public void testFindByStatus() throws ParseException {
    for (PersonStatus status : PersonStatus.values()) {
        List<Person> personlist = PersonRepository.findByStatus(status);
        assertThat(personlist, notNullValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you solve the org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException ? I don't understand it from your answer.

Comment: @AlessandroC the OP was trying to mock an enum which was triggering the exception. In my answer I suggest not to mock the enum, which solves the problem

Comment: Ah, ok... Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem, but thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 17):

Just to complete the picture:

The latest version of Mockito 2 very well supports mocking of final classes. But you have to explicitly enable this new experimental feature first!

( see [here](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.15.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39) on how to do that - it boils down to add a file `mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` to your classpath, containing the value `mock-maker-inline` )

But of course: you only mock something if you have to. Your desire to mock Enum instances is most likely driven by  either not understanding that - or because you created hard to test code here. In that sense the real answer would be to look into ways that avoid this kind of mocking in the first place.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer even though the OPs case can be handled without mocking the enum.

Comment: Had same scenario and ended up passing information I needed from the enum to method so that method is testable with params I could manipute. From `fooMethod(FooEnum myEnum)` to `fooMethod(String data1FromEnum, Stirng data2fromEnum)`. Now easier to test but less cleaner in my opinion, especially if you have lots or params. If you have a lot, rather use a DTO object which you can mock too like `fooMethod(DtoClassWithEnumVars dto);`

Answer (score 5):

As already mentioned, using Mockito 2 and enabling experimental features.

What is actually missing, is an example snippet to demonstrate how.
Considering an enum called `LicenseHistoryAction` with 4 already existing values, this will properly mock an `UNSUPPORTED` one:

```
try (MockedStatic<LicenseHistoryAction> licenseHistoryActionMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(LicenseHistoryAction.class)) {
    final LicenseHistoryAction UNSUPPORTED = Mockito.mock(LicenseHistoryAction.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(4).when(UNSUPPORTED).ordinal();

    licenseHistoryActionMockedStatic.when(LicenseHistoryAction::values)
            .thenReturn(new LicenseHistoryAction[]{
                    LicenseHistoryAction.ASSIGN,
                    LicenseHistoryAction.RELEASE,
                    LicenseHistoryAction.UNBIND,
                    LicenseHistoryAction.DENY,
                    UNSUPPORTED});
}
```